# Find largest subarray length in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I made a function for finding largest subarray length. It works fine but with some input it doesn't show the correct output.

Here is my code:

```js
    function maxLength(a, k) {
      function sumOfArray(arr) {
        return arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
      }

      var sub_array = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
          if (j - i > sub_array.length && sumOfArray(a.slice(i, j)) < k) {
            sub_array = a.slice(i, j);
          }
        }
      }
      return sub_array.length;
    }


console.log(maxLength([3,1,2,1,4], 4))
```

The input which shows wrong answer is: [3,1,2,1,4] and `k = 4` which the output is 2 but the correct answer is 3

How can I fix the code

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: what does the subarray contain?

Comment: So what is an example of an input that is wrong, what is one that is right?

Comment: @epascarello I mentioned in the question the case which is wrong and the correct answer for that

Comment: One that works would help as well.  But there are two parameters to the function.  For what value of `k` does `[3,1,2,1,4] ` not work?

Comment: @ScottSauyet It's 4

Comment: So do expect 3 because it's the length of `[1, 2, 1]`?  If so, then you need to change `< k` to `<= k`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I tried this before but it returns the same output

Comment: I have no clue what "sub array length" means so really of no help. How many numbers you can use that  sum equal to the number?

Comment: I think I understand.  We want to find the length of the longest sub-array of the input array with terms that sum to no more than the value `k`.  So for `maxLength([[3,1,2,1,4] , 4)` we return 3, since that is the length of `[1, 2, 1]`, which is the longest subarray of the input whose length is no more than 4.  Is that correct?

Comment: @ScottSauyet yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing with different cases finally I got that some part of the code should be changed.

First `for` loop must `i <= a.length` and also second `for` loop `j <= a.length`

Also in `if` statement `sumOfArray(a.slice(i, j)) < k` should be change to:

`sumOfArray(a.slice(i, j)) <= k`

These changes show the correct answer for all cases.

So here is the code:

```
function maxLength(a, k) {
function sumOfArray(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}

var sub_array = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
  for (var j = i + 1; j <= a.length; j++) {
    if (j - i > sub_array.length && sumOfArray(a.slice(i, j)) <= k) {
      sub_array = a.slice(i, j);
    }
  }
} 
return sub_array.length;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong the you are trying the subarray with max length whoes `sum` is as `input`(k).

For this change in your `if condition`=> **`< k`** to **`< =k`**

```
if (j - i > sub_array.length && sumOfArray(a.slice(i, j)) < k)
```

to

```
if (j - i > sub_array.length && sumOfArray(a.slice(i, j)) <= k)
```

```js
function maxLength(a, k) {
  function sumOfArray(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  }

  var sub_array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
      if (j - i > sub_array.length && sumOfArray(a.slice(i, j)) <= k) {
        sub_array = a.slice(i, j);
      }
    }
  }
  return sub_array.length;
}
console.log(maxLength([3,1,2,1,4],4));
console.log(maxLength([3,1,2,1,4],7));
console.log(maxLength([1,1,1,1,3,1,2,1,4],7));
```

Comment: I have tried this before. But it shows the same output

Answer (score 0):

@NullPointer gave the simple modification that seems to make your function work.  Here is another approach that I think simplifies the problem:

```js
const sum = (xs) => xs.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
const range = (lo, hi) => [...new Array(hi - lo + 1)].map((_, i) => i + lo);

const subarrays = (arr) => arr
  .map((x, i) => range(i + 1, arr.length + 1).map(j => arr.slice(i, j)))  
  .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [[]])

const maxLength = (arr, limit) => Math.max.apply(null,
  subarrays(arr)
    .filter(xs => sum(xs) <= limit)
    .map(xs => xs.length)
)

console.log(maxLength([3, 1, 2, 1, 4], 4))
```

- `sum` gives the sum of the values in an array.
- `range` creates an array of numbers between `lo` and `high`
- `subarrays` lists the subarrays of an array.  For instance `subarrays([2, 3, 5])`
  returns `[[], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 5], [3], [3, 5], [5]]`

and of course

- `maxLength` is the function you're trying to write.

There are certainly potential efficiencies lost in this approach, involving not having to test subarrays that extend one that already exceeds the limit.  But those efficiencies are not used in the original either.

`sum` and `range` here are clearly reusable functions, and it's possible that `subarrays` might also come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues with the above:

- is not defensive (i could also check type in my code)
- starts at the smallest blocks, do the biggest spans first so you can terminate early

Try:

```
function maxLength(a, k) {
  if(!a || !k) return 0
  for(let scanlen = a.length; scanlen; scanlen--){
    for(let start = 0; start+scanlen<=a.length; start++){
      if( a.slice(start, start+scanlen).reduce((acc,curr)=> acc+curr ) <= k)
         return scanlen
    }
  }
  return 0
}
```